# html code tables is not workinig

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i cannot show any values and i dont get any error messages. . here is my code:

```
    Number: <input type="text" name="number" />
            <br>
            <% Persone =(Employqq)request.getAttribute("cust"); %>
            <table id="table" border="1">
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Number</th>
                </tr>
                for(Employee t : emp){ %>

                <tr>
                      <td>
                     <%= t.getnumber() %>
                      </td>




                <% } } %>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

i appreciate all the help that i can get

Comment: I do not know much about jsp but I think you are naming the customer `c` and then in your view you try to call it as `t`. Another observation, are you relaoding the page when the form is sent or is that code being executed dynamically?

Comment: @pablito.aven No, `t` is a `Ticket` instance

Answer (score 0):

You set the attribute in your servlet as `Cust`, and in your JSP you read it as `cust`

Comment: thank you, it helped! But i wonder, how can i add a value in a specific column? all the values ends up under the first column, insedd of the whole row?

Comment: This is because you are opening and closing a row tag `<tr>` with every table data cell tag `td`

Comment: You should have it one <tr> </tr> for all the `<td></td>` `<td></td>` `<td></td>` tags

Comment: @Hanna Also if you believe that this answer is good enough to fix your issue, kindly mark it as accepted.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer